# Test case failing in mocha & chai - LitElement

Tags: mocha.js, chai, lit-element, lit-html

I have started looking at the **`lit-html`** and was trying to write some unit test cases using **`mocha`** & **`chai`** with a simple component file, but it is failing with the below error.

[image]

**Test case:**

```js
var assert = require('chai').assert;
var emp = require('../src/components/employee/emp-component').greeting;

describe('Emp', function () {
    it('should return hello', function () {
        assert.equal(emp(), 'hello');
    });
});
```

**Component:**

```js
import {
    LitElement,
    html
} from 'lit-element';

class EmpComponent extends LitElement {

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    greeting() {
        return 'hello';
    }
}

customElements.define('emp-component', EmpComponent);
```

Is there an other way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `open-wc` helpers to create `lit-element` test cases. [open-wc helpers](https://open-wc.org/testing/testing-helpers.html)

**step 1**: once., installed `open-wc`., import `fixture`

```js
import {fixture, html} from '@open-wc/testing'
```

**step 2**: use `async` & `await` till your component is loaded. `fixture` helps understand lit-element

```js
import {fixture, html} from '@open-wc/testing'

describe('test case', () => {
  it('case', async () => {
    const elem = await fixture(html`<your-component></your-component`);
  })
})
```

Once component is loaded., your test cases starts triggering. For more information on polymer 3 & lit. refer [Sabarinath blog on polymer & litElements](https://jsabarinath.wordpress.com/)

Comment: Still getting the same error. I have this node script while running the test. Something like this:

`"scripts": { "test": "mocha" }` Anything needs to be changed here?

Comment: can you try `karma` over `mocha`. create karma.conf.js file and run `karma` test cases